# Can't process input text from Preview app in macOS Catalina for Automator's service

Tags: macos, preview, macos-catalina

I have a Quick Action made with Automator that will google search the highlighted content.

[My Quick Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUkg4.png)

```
function run(input, parameters) {   
    return "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURI(input);
}
```

[The error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xzOS.png)

It did work fine before and still works by now except for the Preview application after updating to macOS Catalina. The Preview was opening a PDF file that was converted from a Word document. I've tried many other types of PDF documents but got the same results. Then I tried opening said PDF documents with other programs and it worked. So the problem should lie in how the Preview app handling out the input to the service. I like the Preview app and it would be a hassle to switch to another app just because of this. Is there any workaround in the javascript code or something for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face the very same problem with Preview (trying to automate not Google Search rather Google Translate). As a workaround I use special workflow that receives no input, but uses "Get Contents of Clipboard" (available in the Automator Library) as the first step. As result I have to Cmd-C before I invoke the workflow, but that's better than nothing.

Comment: That's pretty good. In fact, you can further this outside of the Preview app by assigning a shortcut to the service and now you can google search/translate your clipboard anytime, anywhere.